# How do I iterate three or more arrays in the same Swift loop?

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, zip

Iterating one array:

```
for item in myArray {
    print(item)
}
```

Iterating two arrays:

```
for (item1, item2) in zip(myArray1, myArray2) {
    print(item1, item2)
}
```

But what about three or more arrays?

Comment: are all your array same length?

Comment: Yes, they are :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it this way, below is for 2 arrays

```
zip([11,12,12], [12,13,14]).forEach { (i1, i2) in
    print(i1, i2)
}
```

if array length are same them you can use this, easy way

```
for index in 0...firstArray.count {
    print(firstArray[index]) //First Array
    print(secondArray[index]) //Second Array
    print(thirdArray[index]) //Third Array
}
```

Alternative way to workaround will be like this,

```
for index in firstArray.enumerated() {
    print(firstArray[index]) //First Array
    print(secondArray[index]) //Second Array
    print(thirdArray[index]) //Third Array
}
```

Comment: Awesome! The second one did it for me! Thanks a lot for your help and taking the time. This will certainly help optimising my code :)